# Spark Scala groupByKey and flatMapGroups give empty dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to perform grouping operation on a `DataFrame` and perform some manipulation at `Row` level and finally create a `DataFrame`.

Input table :

```
inputDF.show()
```

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|ckey        |twkey            | s_date             |
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|    99227100|         42222245|2018-04-26          |
|    99227100|         42222245|2018-05-01          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2015-12-20          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2016-11-27          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2016-12-19          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2017-08-05          |
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

here is the code I have tried but getting a empty dataframe

```
def encoder(columns: Seq[String]): Encoder[Row] = RowEncoder(StructType(columns.map(StructField(_, StringType, nullable = true))))


val outputCols = Seq("ckey","twkey","s_date")


val result = inputDF.groupByKey(_.get("ckey"))
  .flatMapGroups((_, rowsForEach) => {

    var list1:List[Row] = List()
    var list2:List[Row] = List()

    for (elem <- rowsForEach) {
      val newRow = elem
      println(newRow.getAs[String]("ckey"))
      //if(list1.isEmpty) /*some more conditions to check*/ list2 :+ newRow
      //else /*some more conditions to check*/ list1 :+ newRow
      list1 :+ newRow
    }
    list1
  })(encoder(outputCols)).toDF

result.sort("ckey","twkey","s_date").show()
```

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|ckey        |twkey            | s_date             |
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Why is the `list1 : List[Row]` is getting empty after end of the loop ?

Expected Result:

Since I have not implemented any if condition the expected output should be the same as inputDF

```
result.show()
```

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|ckey        |twkey            | s_date             |
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|    99227100|         42222245|2018-04-26          |
|    99227100|         42222245|2018-05-01          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2015-12-20          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2016-11-27          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2016-12-19          |
|    34011381|         42830849|2017-08-05          |
+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Can you add what output you are expecting for the input example dataframe?

Comment: @Shaido ...since i have not implemented any if condition the expected output should be the same as inputDF

Comment: No, I mean: What is the point of all the code? What are you trying to achive? There should exist some better way to get the result you actually want, getting back a `List[Row]` defeats the purpose of using Spark (it's not distributed).

Comment: Basically I need to create sub records for each parent record after grouping by ckey.So I am thinking to took two list and populate it and return a data frame . Something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297455/creation-of-new-subrows-in-scala-spark-dataframes

Comment: You could check if `collect_list` would help you. More is hard to say without more detailed information.

Comment: I have tried  collect_list  also, it is hitting the performance and job is failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this below code:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("testApp")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val ds = Seq(("99227100", "42222245", "2018-04-26"),
  ("99227100", "42222245", "2018-05-01"),
  ("34011381", "42830849", "2015-12-20"),
  ("34011381", "42830849", "2016-11-27"),
  ("34011381", "42830849", "2016-12-19"),
  ("34011381", "42830849", "2017-08-05")).toDS()

//.toDF("ckey", "twkey", "s_date")

ds.show()

def encoder(columns: Seq[String]): Encoder[Row] = RowEncoder(StructType(columns.map(StructField(_, StringType, nullable = false))))

val outputCols = Seq("ckey", "twkey", "s_date")

val result = ds.groupByKey(_._1)
  .flatMapGroups((_, rowsForEach) => {
    val list1 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
    for (elem <- rowsForEach) {
      list1.append(Row(elem._1, elem._2, elem._3))
    }
    list1
  })(encoder(outputCols)).toDF

result.show()
```

> Output:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|    ckey|   twkey|    s_date|
+--------+--------+----------+
|34011381|42830849|2015-12-20|
|34011381|42830849|2016-11-27|
|34011381|42830849|2016-12-19|
|34011381|42830849|2017-08-05|
|99227100|42222245|2018-04-26|
|99227100|42222245|2018-05-01|
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** You can use `List` and `var` like this.

**Explanation**:

Let's look at this parts of the code:

```
var list1: List[Row] = List()
...
list1 :+ newRow
```

Scala `List` is immutable. `var` denotes a variable. It means that the reference can resigned.

```
list1 = Nil
```

or

```
list1 = List(Row(42))
```

but it doesn't affect mutability of list. Every time you call

```
list1 :+ newRow
```

you create a new list and discard the result.

To store anything you should you should reassign the result:

```
list1 = list1 :+ newRow
```

but you don't really want to append to `List` in a loop. Prepending would be better

```
list1 = newRow :: list1
```

but in practice just one of the `collections.mutable`.

**Note**:

Also we don't really use `groupByKey` with `Dataset[Row]`. Most of the time there are more efficient ways of dealing with it, but it is different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an immutable List, += returns a new list with the added parameter (which you're ignoring).
Instead, use:

> new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]